# Using Excel to Modify CRs in ClearQuest in C#

Tags: c#, database, excel, clearquest

The way that I was doing this before, was putting Metadata into each individual CR and having the query exported to an excel file. The program would read the Metadata then create new columns with values in them depending on the CR Id number. Is there a way to do this backwards? Where when you change the excel sheet it can modify the CR? How should I go about doing this? Links to get me started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out half of the problem, just accessing clearQuest and being able to make changes accordingly. Next I have to get the xml from excel and transfer it into clearQuest.

```
using ClearQuestOleServer;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            String defectNumber = "L12345678";
            Session cqsession = new Session();

            try
            {
                cqsession.UserLogon(loginName, password, databaseName, sessionType, databaseSet);
                ClearQuestOleServer.IOAdEntity defect = cqsession.GetEntity("defect", defectNumber) as ClearQuestOleServer.IOAdEntity;

                cqsession.EditEntity(defect, "modify");

                String val = defect.GetFieldValue("User Data") as String;
                defect.SetFieldValue("UserData", "Test String");

                string result = defect.Validate();
                //if (defect.Validate() == null)
                //defect.Commit();
                //else
                //defect.Revert();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                int a = 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also along with that I was able to create a serializer that creates xml for the columns in excel, so in turn you can extract the data from excel change it into xml, then use the code above to import into the specific fields. Works like a charm.